# Picture equation with curly brace

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer

I'm trying to add the following to my beamer slideshow:

[image]

A, B and C are images and I need them to appear one by one (A, then B, then C). When figure C shows up, the plus sign and curly brace should become visible as well.

I'm currently using tabular environment for that, but I don't know how to add the curly brace. This is my code:

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \visible<1-3>{\includegraphics{A.eps}} & \visible<3>{+} & \visible<2-3>{\includegraphics{B.eps}} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\visible<3>{\includegraphics{C.eps}}} \\                 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

1. Is there any better way than using a table?
2. How can I create a horizonatal curly brace?

Comment: Please, as usual, provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this may be an overkill to create this pic only, it allows you to generally generate such setups.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Some pics}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.3ex]
 \node[visible on=<1-3>](A) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
 \node[right=of A,visible on=<3>] (plus) {$+$};
 \node[right=of plus,visible on=<2-3>](B){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};
 \draw[visible on=<3>,decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,
    amplitude=7pt,raise=0.5ex},thick] (B.south east) -- (A.south west) 
    node[midway,below=0.8em](C){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use a `tabular`, exploiting `\upbracefill`, which is the auxiliary macro for `\underbrace`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Addition}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\visible<1-3>{\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}} &
\visible<3>{+} &
\visible<2-3>{\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-b}} \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\visible<3>{\upbracefill}} \\[1ex]
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\visible<3>{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}}}
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]